# Import "django.urls" could not be resolved from source

Tags: python, django

[image: my]

I am expecting the solve please help me I m new at that.
I tried searching but I could not find anything.

Comment: Simply restart the VS code.

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you were running this from the command prompt, what you would do is `python ./manage.py shell` to get a shell with all of the Django infrastructure + your apps + your settings.  Then in the python repl you can `import django.urls` and so forth.  (This may give someone some ideas on how to do it in VS Code ...)

Answer (score 2):

step 1: Click on the bottom left of the screen to change python interpreter.
[as shown in image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/as4WI.jpg)

step 2: try changing that interpreter to any other interpreter that best suits your project.

If the problem still exists even after changing the interpreter try restarting vscode again.
I hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

Try to restart your code editor and instead of running `django.url` in your terminal, try running `python manage.py runserver`.

Comment: i tried and not worked

Comment: are you using the correct env?

Comment: oh i don't know buddy how can i learn

Comment: but i guess i have a library problem and i cant fix it

Comment: can i send my code to you